# Multisite Posting Recent Items in All the Sites Linked with Multisite

Tags: multisite

Multisite Posting Recent Items in All the Sites Linked with Multisite. 
I have a Multisite and linked 2 sites in it with 2 different languages English and Telugu. I am trying to display some recent Telugu posts list in English site and some English posts in Telugu site.

Can anyone help me by saying the possibilities for this or need to add the items manually on both the sites?

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884987/how-can-i-display-posts-from-the-other-sites-in-a-wordpress-multisite-setup) should help you.